# MSDEPLOY access issue on Windows 2003 and IIS6

Tags: msdeploy

I have created a web deployment package for a web application from VS 2010. I am trying to deploy it using msdeploy on a Win Serevr 2003 IIS 6 machine. The remote agent service is running. When I run the command (cmd file), I get the following warning:

```
Warning: Access to the path 'MsDepSvc.exe' is denied. Retrying operation 'Delete' on object dirPath (\\localhost\C$\WINDOWS\TEMP\MSDEPLOY\5e16dc0d-6bfc-4398-b773-bfd8c504c0bc). Attempt 1 of 5.
```

I am an administrator on the machine. IUSR, NETWORKSERVICE and ASPNET have full control over the folder - C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\MSDEPLOY. I am an administrator on the machine. How can I overcome this warning? The deployment is failing because of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the msdeploy command line tool as follows

```
msdeploy -verb:sync source:package="***.zip location" dest:iisApp="iis 6 website"
```

iisApp provider can be used with both IIS 6 and 7. If your deployment works using the above command through command line, it may help you to pin point the issue.